# Obter ID de um processo

Tags: c

Queria obter um ID de um processo , pois gostaria de usar o `kill()` para enviar sinais de um processo para esse. Sei que para obter o ID do próprio processo usa-se `getpid()` no entanto não sei como obter o ID de um processo do qual apenas sabemos o nome. ***Como poderei fazer isto ?***

Comment: Qual sistema operacional?

Comment: Se puder usar C++ e for Windows, você pode obter todos os processos que estão a rodar com a função [EnumProcesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx), da biblioteca `Windows.h`. Daí é só buscar pelo nome e matar.

Comment: @Renan Linux Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: No windows, se você souber o nome do processo pode usar o kill direto pelo nome dele, exemplo : taskkill /f /im notepad.exe

Answer (score 1):

No linux, não se existe uma maneira padrão para se obter PID de um processo a partir do seu nome, uma interessante aproximacao é a varredura do diretório `/proc` em busca de todos os PIDs relacionados ao processo:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int obter_pids( const char * name, pid_t * pids, int * count )
{
    DIR * dir = NULL;
    struct dirent * ent = NULL;
    char * endptr = NULL;
    char buf[512] = {0};
    int i = 0;

    dir = opendir("/proc");

    if (!dir)
        return -1;

    while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        long lpid = strtol( ent->d_name, &endptr, 10 );

        if( *endptr != 0 )
            continue;

        snprintf( buf, sizeof(buf), "/proc/%ld/comm", lpid );

        FILE * fp = fopen(buf, "r");

        if( !fp )
            continue;

        if(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp))
        {
            buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;

            if( !strcmp( buf, name ) )
                pids[i++] = lpid;
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }

    closedir(dir);

    *count = i;

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    pid_t pid[ 100 ];
    int count = 0;
    int ret = 0;

    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Sintaxe: %s NOME_DO_PROCESSO\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    ret = obter_pids( argv[1], pid, &count );

    if( ret == -1 )
    {
        printf("Processo '%s' nao encontrado!\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    for( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        printf( "%d ", pid[i] );

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ gcc pidname.c -o pidname
```

Repare que o mesmo processo pode possuir n instancias, o que nos dá um PID para cada uma delas.

Espero ter ajudado!